On swagger from php comments, how set a array of objects on parameters?
I have a parameters called items, and it is a array of objects...
I am trying
   *     @OA\Parameter(
     *          name="itens",
     *          in="query",
     *          required=true,
     *          description="Array of objects with itens to credit (Ex.: [{id_produto:50, qtde:25, valor_unitario:150}, {id_produto:51, qtde: 5, valor_unitario: 20}])",
     *          @OA\JsonContent(
     *              type:
     *          )
     *          @OA\Schema(
     *              type="array",
     *              items= @OA\Items(
     *                  type="object",
     *                  properties= @OA\JsonContent(
     *
     *                  )
     *              )
     *          )
     *      ),

How I can do it?
I need pass this parameters
